# Trasferring a list of rows from one table to another

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, mysqli

I have searched everywhere but couldn't find a viable solution to this. Maybe i'm not going about this the right way. 
I have a list of comma separeated values in an array of ID's which refrences image_id's in a 'temp_image' table. Now i need to slect all the info about the all the images with image_id's in that array and tranfer them form the 'temp_image' table to the 'images' table.

$IMgids = array(1,2,3,4,5,9); etc
how does my query look like? 
What should my where clause look like.
I'm comfortable with transfering one row but in this case it could be as much as 50 rows. 
Any ideas how i could go about this?

Comment: can you please give your table structure

Comment: Oh sorry,I didn't think the table structure was needed as the question was "how to select multiple rows from a table and transfer it to another table". It would be the same for any table structure with a unique ID, provided it's not relational.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the little information you posted I'd say you need these two details:

1. the `IN` operator for the `WHERE` clause, so that you can reference all entries that are referenced by your array at once: `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4,5,9);`. You probably want to construct the id set inside the clause by using phps `implode()` function: `implode(',',$IMgids)`
2. the sub query principle for inserting multiple rows into a table that are read from another table. Consult the mysql (online) documentation for this. Something like this: `INSERT INTO images (SELECT * FROM temp_images WHERE...);`

Comment: I also tried to find something like  inserting multiple rows into a table that are read from another table but didn't succeed and after i have to do it by function calls . Link for above problem will be appreciated .

Comment: Ha, thank youu. Exactly what i needed. I'm implementing it now :)

Comment: @chetan: Well with arkascha's idea you can do it in less than 7 lines of query.